# How to create dynamic sheet references with cell text in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup, cross-reference

I am working with a large workbook and I want to drag formulas across to reference the title of their column with the corresponding sheet of the same name.

In this example: =VLOOKUP($B3,'04.22 NE'!$B$2:$G$475,6,FALSE)
I am wondering what to change "04.22 NE" to reference the text within the cell above (V2) that as that is the sheet to lookup.

[image: Photo of Sheet]

Comment: Google Sheets?  Excel?  Some sample data that shows what you expect to get at the end.

Comment: Apologies - this is in excel. 

EXAMPLE: 

 Cell A3 = **CELL TEXT**

 Cell B3 =VLOOKUP($B3,'**CELL TEXT**'!$B$2:$G$475,6,FALSE)

Where **CELL TEXT** is the text within a cell that is the same as the sheet name to reference. 

Therefore I want the formula to understand that the text (A3) is the sheet name to lookup. 

(the photo of sheet above helps)

Comment: Add the additional text from your comment into the question soi it doesn't get missed as comments pile up or are removed.

Answer (score 0):

##### INDIRECT

`=VLOOKUP($B3,INDIRECT(R3&"!$B$2:$G$475"),6,FALSE)`

|  | R | S | T |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 100 | 93.8 | 93.5 |
| 3 | **03.22 E** | **04.22 NE** | **04.22 AL** |
| 4 | `=VLOOKUP($B3,INDIRECT(R3&"!$B$2:$G$475"),6,FALSE)` | `=VLOOKUP($B3,INDIRECT(S3&"!$B$2:$G$475"),6,FALSE)` | `=VLOOKUP($B3,INDIRECT(T3&"!$B$2:$G$475"),6,FALSE)` |

<sub>**NOTE**:  *In the solution the range  `$B$2:$G$475` will not update dynamically since it is included as a text string `"!$B$2:$G$475"`.  If you change it from absolute values in the future you will need to do something similar to that portion of the address as we did for the sheet name.*</sub>